open-webapi XboxLiveClient.message.send_message() format
I am building a project that uses xbox-webapi and I need to find out the format for the xuid messaging here is my code for the auth script
async def send_message(auth_mgr, recipient_xuid, message_text, client_session):
    xbl_client = XboxLiveClient(auth_mgr=auth_mgr)
    try:
        formatted_xuid = "["+recipient_xuid+"]"
        print(formatted_xuid)
        await xbl_client.message.send_message(
            xuid=recipient_xuid,
            message_text=message_text
        )
        print(f"Message sent to XUID {recipient_xuid}: {message_text}")
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print(f"Failed to send message: {e}")

But keep on getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/######/Desktop/######/Project Xetram/xbox_messaging_debug.py", line 50, in send_message
    await xbl_client.message.send_message(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xbox/webapi/api/provider/message/__init__.py", line 133, in send_message
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_models.py", line 761, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPStatusError(message, request=request, response=self)
httpx.HTTPStatusError: Client error '400 Bad Request' for url 'https://xblmessaging.xboxlive.com/network/Xbox/users/me/conversations/users/xuid(######)'

I dont know if there is a correct format for the script or its just the apipremissions for my application is not set.
I expected it to send my message to my xbox account but its not working
